# Objective C-unknown class method for selector

Tags: objective-c

I have a class method

```
+ (NSString *)calcRemaingTimeToDate:(NSDate *)startDate:(NSDate *)endDate;


- (void)calcRemaingTime
{
    if (self.meeting.startTime) {
        self.timeToMeetingOutput.text:self startDate = [AppContext calcRemaingTimeToDate:self.meeting.startTime];
        CGRect bound = [self.timeToMeetingOutput.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(278.f, 16.f)
                                                                   options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                                attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: self.timeToMeetingOutput.font}
                                                                   context:nil];
        self.timeToMeetingWidth.constant = bound.size.width + 10.f;
    }
```

But getting an error like no known class method for selector 'calcRemaingTimeToDate'.
I am not getting the error.Anyone please help me out.

Comment: Include the actual error message.

Comment: because your method declaration says `+ (NSString *)calcRemaingTimeToDate:(NSDate *)startDate:(NSDate *)endDate;
` but you are calling `calcRemaingTimeToDate:` you missed out `endDate:` portion.

Comment: @VivekMolkar, Why not post that as an asnwer.

Comment: @l'L'l  made it an answer. :-)

Comment: Look at @Shabib's answer. He has explained very thoroughly. I would say, if you really don't want to specify the label for the second parameter then at least put a space in between (NSDate *)startDate: and (NSDate *)endDate;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class method:

```
+ (NSString *)calcRemaingTimeToDate:(NSDate *)startDate:(NSDate *)endDate;
```

Has two parameters, but in your code you're only passing one:

```
[AppContext calcRemaingTimeToDate:self.meeting.startTime];
```

For this reason, the compiler is not recognizing the method. This method should be called as something like this:

```
[AppContext calcRemaingTimeToDate:self.meeting.startTime :secondParam];
```

There is also another problem in the declaration of your method, you've not specified the method name part for the second parameter, your method name should be something like this:

```
+ (NSString *)calcRemaingTimeFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toDate:(NSDate *)endDate;
```

And it should be called like:

```
[AppContext calcRemaingTimeFromDate:self.meeting.startTime toDate:secondParam];
```

Also in your code, this `self.timeToMeetingOutput.text:self startDate` seems to be in invalid syntax.

Comment: My class method is in AppContext.h file & calcRemaingTime method is in ContentViewController.m file ,I changed in the method as self.timeToMeetingOutput.text = [AppContext calcRemaingTimeToDate:self.meeting.startTime toDate:(NSDate *)endDate];  error-use of undeclared identifier 'endDate'.I want to use startDate & endDate both.How to do that.Please suggest.

Comment: @Rini, in your AppContext.h declare `+ (NSString *)calcRemaingTimeFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toDate:(NSDate *)endDate; ` and in the AppContext.m file implement the method `+ (NSString *)calcRemaingTimeFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toDate:(NSDate *)endDate { //your implementation }`, and then call this method from where you need as `[AppContext calcRemaingTimeFromDate:self.meeting.startTime toDate:secondParam];`. Also don't forget to `#import 'AppContext.h'` in the class where you're using this method.

Answer (score 1):

Your method declaration says

```
 + (NSString *)calcRemaingTimeToDate:(NSDate *)startDate:(NSDate *)endDate;
```

but you are calling `calcRemaingTimeToDate:` you missed out `endDate:` portion.

Passing second parameter should solve the problem.